# Equivalent of PHP's crypt function in Java

Tags: java, php, encryption

I am migrating my PHP code to Google App Engine - Java.
So I need an equivalent of PHP's crypt function in Java,
since I have stored all the passwords of registered users
using crypt in my DB.

**Edit 1**: 
Here is my php code for encrypting passwords :

$password = "test123";
$pwd = crypt($password,$password);
echo $pwd;

Output is (On **Windows** as well as a linux based server on **HostMonser**):
**temjCCsjBECmU**

Can someone give me equivalted java code?
I have tried various permutations & combinations with
MessageDigest class, but can't get it right..

**Edit 2**:
Here is sample code which I thought would work but did not:

```
try {
                {
                    String password = "test123";
                    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance( "MD5" ); 
                    byte[] passwordBytes = password.getBytes( ); 

                    digest.reset( );
                    digest.update( passwordBytes );
                    digest.update( passwordBytes );
                    byte[] message = digest.digest( );

                    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
                    for ( int i=0; i < message.length; i++) 
                    {
                        hexString.append( Integer.toHexString(
                            0xFF & message[ i ] ) );
                    }
                    String encrypted = hexString.toString();
                    System.out.println(encrypted);
                  } } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Please tell me you aren't using the default (DES) crypt algorithm.... theres a reason modern unixen don't come with the crypt utility -- it's been broken before.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: PHP's default is OS dependent.  On Linux/BSD, it defaults to salted MD5 (except on really old versions).  Newer versions may even use a newer scheme, like salted SHA512.

Comment: @Billy ONeal:  However, the code that dta *just* posted is indeed DES... must be on a Windows machine with PHP 5.2 or lower.

Comment: With the MessageDigest class, you must NOT call the update() method twice. It result in crypting the password "test123test123" instead of "test123".

Comment: I called it twice as I thought that would take care of the "salt",as in the case of PHP's crypt.

Comment: You aren't using the plain text password as salt, are you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to know what implementation of PHP crypt has been used (MD5? SHA256? SHA512?) because there are several, depending on your OS : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.crypt.php

The Java equivalent class is [MessageDigest](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html). When you create an instance of this class, you provide the hash algorithm, for example :

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
MessageDigest md2 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
MessageDigest md3 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
// etc.
byte[] encryptedPassword = md.digest("yourPassword".getBytes());
```

Comment: That PHP manual page is in French, English version here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: I'm sorry. Thanks for the correction. Since I am french, I did not notice when I posted the response.

Comment: How about crypt with a crypt key? Is there any way of using a crypt key in java, like you would in php? For example crypt($password, "test") would encrypt different than crypt($password) in php...

Comment: Thats not the same: crypt() in PHP is a wrapper of Crypt3 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)

It's not the same as digest, it makes a lot of iterations

Answer (score 12):

This is an old thread but I ran into the same issue and found a different solution.  You can use the UnixCrypt/Md5Crypt classes in the [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) 1.7 library.

For example you can call

```
UnixCrypt.crypt(string, salt)
```

OR

```
Md5Crypt.md5Crypt(byte[], salt)
```

I haven't looked into the other encryption types but I imagine their are other utilities as well.

- [org.apache.commons.codec.digest.UnixCrypt](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/UnixCrypt.html)
- [org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Md5Crypt](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/Md5Crypt.html)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have to work with a legacy database already populated with passwords you cannot discard, so you can't just [switch to a salted MessageDigest](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#MessageDigest), preferably using SHA-1. And your problem gets more complicated, since PHP's crypt is a wrapper that [might use one of several algorithms](http://php.net/manual/de/function.crypt.php). But let's assume your PHP uses the original DES-based UNIX crypt, then all you need is an implementation of that in Java. As far as i know, there is no implementation of UNIX's crypt in the standard Java installation, but you might want to [look here](http://www.dynamic.net.au/christos/crypt/) for a list of options.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a look at the java.security classes (what used to tbe the JCE):

In there you'll find everything you need to do what you want (depending on which algorithm you need).

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/package-summary.html

e.g. MessageDigest for MD5/SHA etc:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html

Check these against the Google App Engine whitelist here, I'm not sure what's supported and what isn't.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html

The java.security stuff can be a bit of a pain to work with sometimes, you may alternatively want to use Jasypt - which is a more simplified API that works with any JCE:

http://www.jasypt.org/

Answer (score 1):

PHP's crypt supports multiple hash functions. If you use the MD5 version (hash starts with $1$), you can find a Java implementation here,

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Groupware/LibreSource/md5/MD5Crypt.java.htm

Please notice that they use their own MD5 class. I am not sure if it's the same as standard MD5.

I am sure you can find Java implementation for other hash algorithms too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, PHP's crypt isn't actually encryption as far as I know.  It's just a wrapper around some one-way hashing functions I believe, so if your current PHP site's using crypt's MD5 or SHA256 or whatever, I'd expect that you could find those equivalent hashing classes/functions in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend this: **[MD5Crypt implementation](http://raginggoblin.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/java-alternative-to-php-crypt-function/)**

```
MD5Crypt.crypt("youPassword"); // output: $1$zSiw0koU$i3Srfmoxx4VPePJHWqAuK/
```

This is one of the few implementations, which works for me.