# Java equivalent for PHP crypt with crypt key

Tags: java, php, md5, crypt

I am trying to find a java equivalent for PHP crypt() function. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292160/equivalent-of-phps-crypt-function-in-java), but the answer says nothing about crypting with a crypt key. I have a PHP website which uses md5 encryption and I have a datatable for users with their passwords encrypted like this

```
crypt($password, CRYPT_KEY)
```

with CRYPT_KEY being a constant. Now I need to use that same datatable for a project in Java. How can I use the Java digest function (or any other md5 encyption function) with a crypt key?

Answer (score 0):

Which hashing algorithm does your combination of php-version/platform use? php's crypt() can choose from a number of algorithms as detailed here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: Actually, I cannot tell exactly. I can see now that this key (or $salt - as it is supposed to be called) should determine the hash type with its prefix. The $salt that is used on the website I am working on is just a random string, so I can't tell which algorithm it uses...

Comment: This is not an answer, this is comment.

Answer (score 0):

The `commons-codec` from Apache has a class `Crypt` that implements this functionality. As of version 1.10, it supports these algorithms:

- `CRYPT_SHA512`
- `CRYPT_SHA256`
- `CRYPT_MD5`
- `CRYPT_STD_DES`