# PHP crypt() and Coldfusion

Tags: php, mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

We are moving away from PHP & MySQL to a pure CF/MSSQL platform and I would like to take our user accounts with us, from MySQL.

The user accounts were originally created on the PHP/MySQL site, and stored with an 8-character salt and the MD5-encrypted password, like so:

- user code: `ISzYi6zf`
- password: `$1$ISzYi6zf$prff0mAKPVBHNKOlRradj1`

With the salt and the encrypted password known to me, I want to be able to "rebuild" the 34 character string from user input in CF, to compare to what is stored in the database.

So far, nothing I have tried in CF has allowed me to "rebuild" the result 34-character string so that I can compare them to what's in the database, ie. I am looking to take user input, add the known salt to it, and come up with a 34 character string in order to compare them.

Thanks for any assistance!

UPDATE:

@Leigh, here is the code that PHP uses to authenticate:

```
<?
    $user_salt = $_POST["user_salt"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $pass_meth = $_POST["pass_meth"];
    if(strlen($user_salt) > 8 && $pass_meth > 0)
    {
        list($salt1, $salt2) = str_split($user_salt, ceil(strlen($user_salt) / 2));
            $salty_password = $salt1.$password.$salt2;
        $pass_to_use =  md5($salty_password);   
    }
    else
    {
        if(strlen($user_salt) > 8)
        {
            $user_salt = "$1$".str_pad(substr($user_salt, 0, 8), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)."$";
        }
        else
        {   
            $user_salt = "$1$".substr($user_salt, 0, 8)."$";
        }
        $pass_to_use = crypt($password, $user_salt);
    }
    echo $pass_to_use;
?>
```

The information we have available in the MySQL DB is as follows:

- user_email: `oli@xxx.com`
- user_code: `$1$xxxxxxxx$`
- user_password: `$1$xxxxxxxx$xxxxxxx`

User password takes the form $1$xxxxxxxx$prff0mAKPVBHNKOlRradj1 - 34 characters, including the prepended user code.

Currently, we are authenticating by having CF send the raw user input (email + password), plus the retrieved user_code (which PHP uses to salt the crypt function) to a PHP page to render the password and compare to what's in the DB.

I am basically at a loss to determine how I can accurately render the user's information in CF, using the existing salt.

Thank you!

Comment: why not just export the (db) data then import it? there shouldn't be any loss/problems

Comment: Also, can you give us a complete example (code, plain text, salt, hashed result) using dummy/throw-away values for comparison?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, our plan was to move the data to MS-SQL server and dump PHP/MySQL entirely; we want to move the data intact, and plan  to authenticate against the same data, but using CF instead of PHP

Comment: @Leigh here is the code PHP uses to authenticate:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I am not a PHP guy).* Ignoring the basic string functions it looks like the key parts of the code involve two functions: `md5` and `crypt`.

### Crypt

From what I have read, there is no built in equivalent of PHP's [crypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php). However, there is a [java implementation of that algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14862726/104223) in the Apache Commons Codec library, which can be used from CF. Download the latest version of [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi) <sup>**</sup>. Then load the jar via [`this.javaSettings`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffe.html) in your Application.cfc file. Once loaded, you can create an instance of the [Md5Crypt class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/Md5Crypt.html) and generate the hash.

**ColdFusion:**

```
Md5Crypt = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Md5Crypt");
salt = "$1$ISzYi6zf$";
data = charsetDecode("some value to hash here", "utf-8");
result = Md5Crypt.md5Crypt(data, salt);
writeDump( Md5Crypt.md5Crypt(data, salt) );
```

**PHP:**

```
$salt = "$1$"."ISzYi6zf"."$";    
$data = "some value to hash here";
$result = crypt($data , $salt);
echo $result;
```

**Result:**

```
$1$ISzYi6zf$lqApYqSEt9fzpSDEZxuK00
```

<sub>** Apache Commons Codec is bundled with CF. However, the bundled jar contains a scaled down version which is missing the MD5Crypt class.</sub>

### MD5

Replicating the md5 result is simpler. The equivalent function in CF is [Hash()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/hash.html). The only difference being CF converts the result to upper case. Use [LCase()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/lcase.html) to match the PHP result:

**ColdFusion:**

```
salt1 = "ISzYi";
salt2 = "6zfXX";
password = "some value to hash here";
WriteOutput( lcase(hash(salt1 & password & salt2)) );
```

**PHP:**

```
$salt1 = "ISzYi";
$salt2 = "6zfXX";
$password = "some value to hash here";
echo( md5($salt1.$password.$salt2) );
```

**Result:**

```
c23d4661e1ef7866a4296658e3335dbc
```

Comment: Leigh, this is really comprehensive, thank you!  I will try this code out and report back!

Comment: this worked really well!  The following code was all that was needed, and returned the appropriate MD5 encrypted password from the MySQL database:

    <cfscript>
    Md5Crypt = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Md5Crypt");
    salt = mycode;
    data = charsetDecode(mypass, "utf-8");
    result = Md5Crypt.md5Crypt(data, salt);
    </cfscript>

    <cfoutput><P>MD5 result again: #result#</cfoutput>

Comment: (Edit) Great! Glad it worked out. I figured you probably had the md5 part worked out already, but thought a complete example might help the next guy :-)

Comment: BTW, when you said "the following .. was all that was needed" I assume you meant for the `else` half of the php function, right? As the code seems to perform different actions depending on the length of the salt and method parameter. So fully replicating it requires both crypt() and md5().

Comment: the authentication mechanism we are moving used two methods over the past 10 years; originally, the crypt() method was used, then they switched to the MD5 method about 6 years ago, which means that we had to build in a switch to check which authentication method the users was linked to; so yes, both the MD5 and Crypt methods get used, but not for the same user.

Comment: Gotcha.. just making sure we were on the same page and that I was not giving confusing advice ;-)

Comment: Not at all; I have been trying to solve this since 2009, and your advice was spot-on!