# How to check Unix credentials in a Java program

Tags: java, bash, unix, authentication, sudo

I have two strings representing a user and a password for that user. I'd like to check if this is a valid authentication pair in a Unix environment.

I thought about running a sudo bash command to authenticate inside Java code and see if the exit value of the command executed is equal to 0.

However I cannot make this work.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String user = "user";
        String pass = "pass\n";

        try{

            Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(
                "/bin/sh","-c","sudo","-S","su",user).start();

            OutputStream os = proc.getOutputStream();
            os.write(pass.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            try{
                System.out.println(proc.waitFor());
            } catch ( InterruptedException e ){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch ( IOException e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This code prints 1 as exit code.
I have really tried everything I could and found on the net but I still have to figure out how to make this work properly.

Can anybody help me?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` asks for the password of the current user, that is, the user that started the java process, so it will not check against `user`'s password.

Instead of `"/bin/sh","-c","sudo","-S","su",user).start();`try `"/bin/sh","-c","su",user).start();`. This will just attempt to switch to that user, and as such will ask for `user`'s password.

Comment: I tried but it returns 127 as exit code. It seems like it doesn't find the command (?)..

Comment: Seems that running su in this way requires a command. Try `"/bin/sh","-c","su",user,"-c", "echo -n").start();`

Comment: Thx for the help but I still got 127 exit code this way

Comment: Try `"/bin/sh","-c","su " +  user + " -c \"echo -n\""`, if that doesn't work I honestly don't know what is going on with your system.

Comment: Now it gets interesting. If I choose a correct username and password exit code is 0. if I choose a correct username and wrong password exit code is still 0. If I choose a wrong username exit code is either 125 or I get "Broken pipe" message... I have no idea what's going on

Comment: `su`'s exit code is not documented to not be 0 in case of an incorrect password, however it will print something like `incorrect password`. You might have to parse the console output of the process to find out if login succeeded. Not sure about the broken pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [su.c](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/v8.4/src/su.c) source code [I've wrote a simple java program](https://github.com/mageddo/java-native-examples/blob/ef4eb3e/src/main/java/nativeapi/jna/linux/password/Main.java) that makes the user credentials verification using [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna). It must works on all Unix based distributions that have the libc and crypt libraries, bellow a code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("type the user");
    final String user = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("type password");
    final String password = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("RESULT\n===========================================");
    final SPassword passwd = CLibrary.INSTANCE.getspnam(user);
    if(passwd == null){
        throw new RuntimeException(String.valueOf(Native.getLastError()));
    }

    final String encrypted = Crypt.INSTANCE.crypt(password, passwd.sp_pwdp);
    System.out.printf("matches=%b%n", encrypted.equals(passwd.sp_pwdp));
}

interface Crypt extends Library {
    Crypt INSTANCE = Native.loadLibrary("crypt", Crypt.class);
    String crypt(String key, String salt);
}

interface CLibrary extends Library {
    CLibrary INSTANCE = Native.loadLibrary("c", CLibrary.class);
    Password getpwnam(String username);
    SPassword getspnam(String username);
}
```

Testing

```
git clone https://github.com/mageddo/java-native-examples.git &&\
cd java-native-examples && git checkout -f ef4eb3e &&\
./gradlew clean build fatjar &&\
sudo java -jar build/libs/java-native-examples-all-*.jar
```

out

```
type the user
elvis
type password
*********
RESULT
===========================================
matches=true
```

**Obs**: The drawback is this application must run as root or sudo user, I can't fix that yet, anyway I think it is possible once **su** command don't need, for security reasons(if it is a problem in your context) I suggest to isolate this functionality to a application then call it by REST, Soap, TCP, whatever. this way your current application will not need to run as root.

If you want you can replace crypt function by [apache commons codec lib function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14862726/2979435) that do the same thing.

#### Reference

- [Function to recover user credentials](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getspnam.3.html)
- [Lib for encrypt password in Linux format](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html)