# How to check Unix credentials in Spring Boot

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, unix

I have implemented a Spring authentication service that gets a username and a password and checks if they are right according to the credentials present in the linux system.
The problem is that it has to ask for su permissions, does anyone know if there is a way to do the same thing without using the su permission or at least a better way to do it?
Thank you in advance.

This is my AuthenticationService.java:

```
try{
            Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh","-c","su",user.getUsername()).start();
            OutputStream os = proc.getOutputStream();
            os.write(user.getPassword().getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            try{
                if(proc.waitFor() == 0)
                    System.out.println("Login successful");
                else
                    System.out.println("Wrong login");
            } catch ( InterruptedException e ){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch ( IOException e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47562069/how-to-check-unix-credentials-in-a-java-program also check the `org.jvnet.libpam` for that

Comment: @SergeyBenner yes the link that you posted is the one from which I have taken the implementation, do you know any example of the org.jvnet.libpam?

Comment: you can google it. but think that you just need a library which does that, either by JNI or by other means like libpam sample: https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/org.jvnet.libpam.UnixUser

Comment: Ok thank you very much